# Need to solve a linear system with a sparse n x n matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

I am developing an application in C# language — an electric simulator that uses the node-voltage method in the AC frequency domain.

I need to solve large systems of linear equations (over $\mathbb C$), one for every frequency step. So, for example, when the program calculates a voltage-frequency curve for an electric node, in a $14$ node electric circuit, with $400$ frequency points, it has to solve a $14$-variable linear equation matrix, $400$ times.

Currently I have the solver implemented with dense matrix format, LU factorization. then Gaussian elimination. I took these algorithms from the book *Numeric Methods* from Ward Cheney & David Kincaid.

The example described above, to solve $400$ times, a $14$-variable matrix, takes in my machine, approximately $500$ milliseconds, measured with Visual Studio 2019. Very slow. I need something quicker.

But in practice, the matrices are very sparse, or in other words, low density, so the ideal thing would be to use sparse matrices!

What algorithms I have available to solve quickly linear equations with sparse matrixes?, (remember to be algorithmically solved with programming language C#).

Also I DO NOT need to have ALL variables calculated, only a few of interest, this could speed up the calculation process a little further, I guess..

What algorithms I have available to solve quickly linear equations with sparse matrixes?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you show the structure of these matrices. Where the 0 are located is more important than how many 0 there are.

Comment: Also look at `Math.NET` and `ILNumerics` both of which support some form of structured matrix solvers (symmetric, triangular, etc).

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include how the coefficient matrix is partitioned, and which blocks are zero, symmetric, skew or dense. Without that information, there isn't a general answer to your question. From the 14 variables, there must be some groupings, like 3*3=9 voltages, and 3*(3-1)/2-1 = 5 currents.  **This is crucial information in order to develop an optimized solver for this problem**

Comment: Thank you for trying to help!, the sparse matrix is variable depending on what the user is doing, depending on what the design is the user making on screen, which can be any. because it is a software app, that is why I need a GENERAL and algorithmical way for solving the matrix. Thank you, sorry about the title 14x14 is just an example, i'll correct it to nxn

Comment: You need to know something about the structure of the matrix to answer the question. Otherwise `LU` is the best you can do. For example if you know that the bottom left $m \times m$ submatrix is always zero, you can skip these elements in the inner calculations. You can also try loop unrolling, or calling a numerical library `.dll` compiled in C or Fortran.

Comment: all right, i'll try to figure out how could be the LU factorization algorithm, in the sparse format, I hope it won't consume too much computational power, at least not as much as with the dense format. Thanks very much :)

Comment: C# or any other managed programming language is not a good choice for numerics if performance is important. You need to interface something written, e.g., in C/C++.

Comment: You might try some iterative methods. Also, I would suggest using a solver from library or package rather than writing it yourself.